# uvm raise_objection and drop_objection

Tags: uvm

I am learning UVM and wondering how the objection is working. I thought that the following code (in my derived agent) executes seq.start(sequencer); and after the sequencer finishes, drop_objection is executed to finish the simulation. If it is true, even if I remove raise_objection and drop_objection, it should execute what the sequencer is programmed to do (sending 8 sequence items to DUT). But when I commented out raise_objection and drop_objection, the simulation finishes without sequencer doing anything even though seq.start should have been executed. Please help me to understand how objection works in UVM in this case. The full testbench environment can be found here: 
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3_bM

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      // We raise objection to keep the test from completing
      phase.raise_objection(this);
      begin
        my_sequence seq;
        seq = my_sequence::type_id::create("seq");
        seq.start(sequencer);      
      end
      // We drop objection to allow the test to complete
      phase.drop_objection(this);
    endtask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly what you'd expect to happen, because that is exactly what objections are for - controlling when to stop the simulation. (Strictly speaking "controlling when to end the phase", but usually there is only one phase that consumes time - the *run phase*.)

Basically, if there are no objections raised, the simulation stops. So, when you comment out your code that raises and drops objections, no objections are raised, so the simulation stops immediately (without doing anything).

- You must always raise an objection in any UVM simulation, otherwise
  it will stop immediately;
- you must always drop all objections at some point, otherwise your
  simulation will not ever stop.

Comment: You are right -- the simulation terminated because there was no pending objection. Actually there is one raised objection in other component (i.e., uvm_test) printed "hello world", then dropped objection in 10ns. Thus, after 10ns, there was no objection and simulation terminated, even though uvm_driver is ready to process sequence_item in forever loop. To check this theory, I increased raised objection time window in uvm_test from 10ns to 100ns, and it provided enough time for driver to work even though I did not raised objection in my uvm_agent.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's language it's like you are telling simulator to complete the activity followed by objection before the current phase stops.